# How to verify that text is seen in the given xpath?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using web driver to automate a test case.  I'm trying to verify the text present in the page or not. I'm doing the following, but I don't know how to verify the textPresent is what I'm actually looking for.

```
textPresent = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//span/p")
```

then when I did textPresent.text it's giving the text "An error occured processing Order" where I'm actually looking for "Successfuly added to processing" in the same xpath location.  So in this situation, I want to fail the test case.  How do i do that?

Comment: The straightforward solution is to add id attribute to the paragraph tag, so that you could easily access the element. After that you can access the `text` attribute of the returned object and compare. `//span/p` is a too broad selector and does not guarantee that the returned element is the one you are looking for.

Comment: There is only one particular text in the entire page.  And there is no id associated with this text. :(

Comment: is there only one span on the page though? Include a snippet of your HTML and I'm sure somebody will be able to point out a better selector

Comment: `assert(textPresent == 'Successfully added to processing')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should include a check point to verify the equality of actual text with expected :

```
expectedText = "Successfuly added to processing";
textPresent = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//span/p");

if textPresent != expectedText
   <Write fail condition here e.g. return "Fail" or raise Exception("Fail")>
```

Comment: above is working fine, but i'm hitting a problem in another similar area. I just want to verify the first line exists and then use assert don't want to verify the content after <br>.  How do i do that?

Comment: <div>
<div class="alertbox alert ng-scope alert-success" ng-class="type && "alert-" + type" close="closeAlert($index)" type="alert.type" ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
<button class="close" ng-click="close()" type="button" ng-show="closeable">×</button>
<div ng-transclude="">
<span class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-bind-html-unsafe="alert.msg">
<p>
Successfuly added to execution processing!
<br>
<br>
{"Date":"5/13/2014","$$hashKey":"00F","memberId":"TOP","instrumentType":"MEE","Symbol":"IPL","quantity":"400","price":113.99}
</p>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>